# RecyclerView not displaying without error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have started Android development and till now I had no problem but I tried to insert RecyclerView to my layout and everything is fine there is no error but my RecyclerView itself is not displaying. The code seems right to me.

Here's my code:

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private RVAdapter adapter;

private RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar));

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.goalList);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adapter = new RVAdapter(getApplication(), getData());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplication()));

}

public static List<RVData> getData() {
    List<RVData> data = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] titles = {"Dummy1", "Dummy2", "Dummy3"};

    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        RVData current = new RVData();
        current.goalTitle = titles[i];
        data.add(current);
    }
    return data;
}

public void newGoal(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewGoal.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
style="@style/DefaultLayoutStyle"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar" />


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    style="@style/FABStyle"
    android:onClick="newGoal"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
    app:borderWidth="0dp" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/app_bar">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/goalList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.kellarapps.zeal.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

goal_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/goalRowCB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/goalRowTitle"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/TextColor"
    android:text="@string/dummyTxt"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

RVData.java:

```
public class RVData {
    CheckBox checkBox;
    String goalTitle;

}
```

RVAdapter.java

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.myViewHolder> {

List<RVData> data = Collections.emptyList();
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public RVAdapter(Context context, List<RVData> cData) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data = cData;
}

@Override
public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.goal_row, viewGroup, false);
    myViewHolder holder = new myViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(myViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    RVData current = data.get(position);
    viewHolder.title.setText(current.goalTitle);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}

class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @Bind(R.id.goalRowTitle)
    TextView title;
    @Bind(R.id.goalRowCB)
    CheckBox checkBox;

    public myViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView;
        checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView;
        }
    }
}
```

There is no error but also there is no RecyclerView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that stands out, your item count is hard coded to return 0. You should return the data size in that function like this:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably can save yourself some trouble here:

```
class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @Bind(R.id.goalRowTitle)
    TextView title;
    @Bind(R.id.goalRowCB)
    CheckBox checkBox;

    public myViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView;
        checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView;
    }
}
```

Would be more straight forward with:

```
class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    //@Bind(R.id.goalRowTitle)
    TextView title;
    //@Bind(R.id.goalRowCB)
    CheckBox checkBox;

    public myViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.goalRowTitle);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.goalRowCB);
    }
    }
```

Combine that with the getCount issue blackcj noticed, and you should resolve your problem.  More than likely that is also why you didn't get the Type mismatches for trying to set views that weren't TextView nor Checkboxes as those types...

Comment: @Bind is the new syntax for Butterknife. If using Butterknife, a call to ButterKnife.bind(this, view); in the constructor should also work. http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/